# Digital Ocean and Terraform Build

Tags: terraform, digital-ocean

I created a new project in Digital Ocean called 'NewProjectTest', and I'm trying to build 3 droplets in Terrafrom. I would like the droplets built in NewProjectTest. However, when I run terraform apply, the droplets are being built in the other project. Where am I going wrong?

Link: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/digitalocean/digitalocean/latest/docs/resources/project

## Create a new Web Droplet in the lon1 region

```
resource "digitalocean_droplet" "web" {
count  = 3
image  = "ubuntu-20-04-x64"
name   = "${count.index}"
region = "lon1"
size   = "s-1vcpu-1gb"
}

resource "digitalocean_project" "NewProjectTest" {
name        = "NewProjectTest"
description = "Description"
purpose     = "Description purposes"
environment = "Development"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the terraform page you linked, digitalocean_project contains a [resources field:](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/digitalocean/digitalocean/latest/docs/resources/project#resources)

> a list of uniform resource names (URNs) for the resources associated with the project

In the [example](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/digitalocean/digitalocean/latest/docs/resources/project#example-usage) given on that page, the project contains a reference to the droplet. This makes the connection between project and droplet:

```yaml
resource "digitalocean_droplet" "foobar" {
  name   = "example"
  size   = "s-1vcpu-1gb"
  image  = "ubuntu-22-04-x64"
  region = "nyc3"
}

resource "digitalocean_project" "playground" {
  name        = "playground"
  description = "A project to represent development resources."
  purpose     = "Web Application"
  environment = "Development"
  resources   = [digitalocean_droplet.foobar.urn]
}
```

Source: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/digitalocean/digitalocean/latest/docs/resources/project

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So I am right to assume I need to add the URN to the resource line? and if so, how do I get the URN before the droplet is built?

Comment: I don't use DigitOcean, so I can't try this out, but `terraform plan` runs without errors